# rails 3 actionmailer works in development, but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, dev-to-production

I have an external smtp server I'm using for actionmailer. I have the exact same action_mailer configs in both development and production configs. It works perfectly in development, but when I run it on heroku it I don't get any sort of error, it says "Send mail to me@gmail.com" and yet the test account never gets the email(even checked spam folder).

here is roughly what my config says:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address => "mail.server.com",
 :port => 25,
 :domain => "server.com",
 :user_name => "no-reply@server.com",
 :password => "password",
 :authentication       => :login,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In this server, no. In another one with the same issue, yes. This one is actually a godaddy smtp server I believe.

Comment: do you try to change the authentication method to plain?

Comment: that's really weird.. sorry, but I dont have any other idea about that...

Comment: What does your mailer code looks like? Also what does `heroku logs` says? any errors?

Comment: it's just the standard devise mailer code. All I changed were the configs as I recall. There are 0 errors in the log and it actually says that it's sending the email.

Comment: Please check your production.rb because Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb, so it might possible you are using different configuration for development and production

Comment: that is where I have been doing all of my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Try removing

```
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

From your smtp config block

Comment: I've looked at that page and tried it's suggest and yours and am still having the same issue :-/ thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using deyaled_jobs for sending email, you may need to add a worker dyno to your application.  Even if you're not, it might be worth a try to see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use godaddy for smtp delivery.  First this is what my particular setup looks like:

```
:address => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
:port => 3535,
:domain => 'www.neeis.com',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name => 'user@neeis.com',
:password => 'password'
```

But!  If the problem ONLY occurs when email comes from gmail.com,  then godaddy blocks it, probably something to do with SPAM.  So here is how I solved that,  in my mailer I have something like this:

```
    begin
      EmployeeMailer.emailtoemp(@message).deliver
    rescue
      EmployeeMailer.emailtoempforce(@message).deliver
    end
```

So if the first attempt to deliver the email with the from = 'somebody@gmail.com' fails,  I try to send it with the from = 'webmaster@mysite.com',  and I embed the from address in the body of the email.  It's not a perfect solution,  these are emails generate from my Web users to my employees.  A lot of the time the employee will not notice the from address, and simply click reply,  and they email me, the webmaster.

Comment: These are confirmation emails so the from is consistently from a hosted domain and not gmail. I have tried sending to both a gmail and a work email address with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 587 instead of 25 first.

If this does not work a quick fix would be using the [Heroku Sendgrid plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid). It's free if you are sending less than 200 emails per day.

Comment: connection refused with 587... would perfer not job to sendgrid just yet... but maybe in the future if I can't get this working

Comment: As you don't get any errors: Have you tested sending an email to another email address not ending on *...@gmail.com*?

Comment: I have actually. I sent one to my personal gmail account and one to my work email account^^;

Comment: I've just had a look at some working config of mine where I use sendgrid and found that I use `:domain => 'heroku.com'`. In the Rails API Docs it just says `:domain - If you need to specify a HELO domain, you can do it here.`. It might be worth to try 'heroku.com' or 'herokuapp.com' makes it work, though this is only guessing, and googling `HELO domain` suggests something like "the domain you use must have valid A and MX records for the receiver to accept it", so "heroku.com" might work fine no matter what your actual domain is. The sendgrid docs are using 'heroku.com'.

Comment: The `:domain` config options seems to be optional firstly, so you might even try not providing it.

Comment: Tried without the :domain and then tried it with the heroku domain, but no luck with either. :-/

Comment: Then my only suggestion remains to check out Sendgrid. It's really easy to integrate.